# Android: regarding elements

Tags: android, constructor, element

I have made a custom element to use with xml files, i intend to makes these elements just a data box, my app will simply read these custom elements, transfer that data they hold such as size, x-y location, color... and such. and will just work accordingly.

so i got to the point of constructing an element:

```
public class Feature extends Element  {

        Feature() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
          }

}
```

the "super();" line is marked red as in error, and it says: "The constructor Element is not visible"

can some one explain to me what is going on?

tried adding Context context or AtrributSet attrs, anything i am familier with.. and nothing :{

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think u quite understand what an Element is. An Element refers to the XML mark-up.
For example, if the XML was:

```
        <bookstore>
          <book category="CHILDREN" stuff= “yes”>
            <title>Harry Potter</title>
            <author>J K. Rowling</author>
            <year>2005</year>
            <price>29.99</price>
        </book category>
        </bookstore>
```

The Elements are: bookstore, book, title, author, year, price
    The Nodes are:  bookstore, book, title, author, year, price (separately)
    NodeList= bookstore, book, title, author, year, price (together)
    Attributes= category & stuff
    Text Content= Happy Potter, J K. Rowling, 2005
    Text= “2005” or “29.99”
    Start Tag= `<bookstore>, <book>`
    End Tag= `</bookstore>, </book>`

Also, if u look at the Element Class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html), it say it’s an “Interface Element”. The “Interface” means you have to “implement”, not extends it.

I first suggest u go figure out what XML is. Here is a tutorial on XML: http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/